# Flexbox, align-items correct syntax and usage

Tags: flexbox

I have made several attempts to use the `align-items` command in my CSS code.  I am able to complete all Flexbox "positions" across the Main Axis.  However, when manipulating `<div>`s and such along the Cross Axis(vertically) I have no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with that: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

It should get you up and running.